# no style change when disabling fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do I make my disabled and enabled `<fieldset>` look the same?

i.e. when toggling disabled no difference should be visible

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```css
fieldset{
  opacity:1 !important;
  border:0;
}

fieldset:disabled{
 opacity:1 !important;
}

fieldset:disabled *{
 opacity:1 !important;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <select>
   <option>testing</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: for me your code works

Comment: Could you describe what is having opacity 0? I can't see anything when I inspect in the browser dev tools.

Comment: @AHaworth I need the disabled and enabled fieldset to both look the same, on toggling disabled there should be no difference

Comment: Could you rephrase your question so that is explained? 'Looking the same' doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the opacity of the elements as such. There may be several styling factors.

Comment: @AHaworth I modified the question now, is it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial), note that it is not supported on internet explorer.

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

fieldset:disabled * {
  opacity: initial;
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <select>
   <option>testing</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: but the background and border still appear different, I need it to look as the same as it did when it was enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pointer-events:none;` this disables the form while still keeping the background same

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

.disabled *{
 pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='disabled'>
  <select>
   <option>testing</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

I've used `.disabled *` so that the click events on the fieldset itself can still be detected

Answer (score 0):

One way, making sure it looks the same when disabled, is to explicitly set the various colors as well as the opacity.

```css
fieldset,
fieldset>* {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <select>
    <option>testing</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

add `pointer-events:none;` to the div.